# Tail multiple remote files and pipe the result

Tags: bash, logging, ssh

I'm looking for a way to pipe multiple log files on multiple remote servers, and then pipe the result to another program.

Right now I'm using multitail, but it does not exactly do what I need, or maybe I'm doing something wrong!

I would like to be able to send the merge of all log files, to another program. For example jq. Right now if I do:

`multitail --mergeall -l 'ssh server1 "tail -f /path/to/log"' -l 'ssh server2 "tail -f /path/to/log"' -l 'ssh server3 "tail -f /path/to/log"' | jq .`

for instance, I get this:

`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2`

But more generally, I would like to give the output of this to another program I use to parse and display logs :-)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: What do you expect to happen from that `grep` statement? I wouldn't expect `grep` to do anything useful with an ncurses program like `multitail`, and equally confusingly, that one looks like it is looking at the current directory (`.`) rather then standard input. Do you get the same error without the pipe to `grep`?

Comment: the grep is a typo >< Thx!

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this feat would be to pipe all your outputs together into a [named pipe](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node17.html#SECTION00732000000000000000) and then deal with the output from that named pipe.

First, create your named pipe:  `$ mknod MYFIFO p`

For each location you want to consolidate lines from, `$ tail -f logfile > MYFIFO` (note, the tail -f can be run through an ssh session).

Then have another process take the data out of the named pipe and handle it appropriately.  An ugly solution could be:

`$ tail -f MYFIFO | jq`

Season to taste.